# panda assign column names in method chain

Tags: pandas

I can assign a list as column names in pandas easily in one line, but (how) can I do the same thing in a method chain?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,4]})

new_column_names =['aa', 'bb']

# classical way:
df.columns= new_column_names
```

What I want is to have this a longer method chain:

```
# method chain
(df.some_chain_method(...)
   .another_chain_method(...)
   .assign_columnnames(new_columns_names))
```

You can assume you know the number of columns and it matches `new_column_names`

Comment: With the `filter` function, do you know how many columns are you getting back?

Comment: yes, that was just to show some method chaining, but confusing, sorry about that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-set-axis):

```
df.set_axis(new_column_names, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   aa  bb
0   1   2
1   2   4
```

Note, in older version of pandas `set_axis` defaulted with inplace=True, so you'll need to add `inplace=False` to chain other methods.  Recently, it was changed to inplace=False default.

Example with chaining:

```
df.set_axis(new_column_names, axis=1).eval('cc = aa + bb')
```

Output:

```
   aa  bb  cc
0   1   2   3
1   2   4   6
```

Comment: You can also write the first part as ```df.set_axis(new_column_names, axis='columns')``` if you prefer. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use the `.rename()` method, with the `inplace` option enabled, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2], 'b':[2,4]})
df.rename(columns={"a": "aa", "b":"bb"}, inplace=True)
df
```

which results in

```
    aa  bb
0   1   2
1   2   4
```

Using `rename` means you can change just a subset of the column names.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: This requires to know the current column names